# Why C++ CLI indexed properties does not work in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

There are two project, One C++ CLI with another C# project.
C++ CLI assembly is referenced in C# project.

Everything is just fine except indexed properties which doesn't work.
C++ CLI code :

```
property Nullable< int> PVarInt[System::String^] {
    Nullable<int> get(System::String^ inx){
    }
    void set(System::String^ inx, Nullable< int>  newx){
    }
}
```

That code in C# appears as two set and get method like following :

```
get_PVarInt(..)
set_PVarInt(..)
```

Is this a bug ? is there a solution to fix this ? Why this happened at all ?

Comment: > Use this calling mechanism,But little unsecured. System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); process.StartInfo.FileName = "App.exe"; process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3"; process.Start();

Comment: I wrote a blog post about a class I created when converting a VB.NET application to C#, it might be of use for you. [PropertyWrapper](http://4a47.blogspot.se/2013/03/propertywrapper.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI has indexed properties that will be available from C#:
Example:

```
public ref class ClassWithIndexer
{
private:
    array<int> ^x;
public:
    property int default[int]
    {
        int get(int index)
        {
            return x[index];
        }
        void set(int index, int value)
        {
            x[index] = value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks already I'm using this way. I have ported my properties to classes.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not support indexed properties except for the `this` property.

However the .NET framework does, so when a indexed property created in a language that supports that it will turn up as one `get_Method` and one `set_Method` in C#.

Comment: Is there a solution to fix this ?

Comment: @Mahdi, that depends on what you mean by fix. As long as you are accessing indexed properties in C# created by another language no. But you could fake an index property in C# by creating a property with an object and using that objects indexed this property.